# React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency:

Tags: reactjs

Hello i'm getting this :

> Line 82:5:   React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency:
> 'product'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can
> also do a functional update 'setProduct(p => ...)' if you only need
> 'product' in the 'setProduct' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps   Line
> 95:5:   React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'product'.
> Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a
> functional update 'setProduct(p => ...)' if you only need 'product' in
> the 'setProduct' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

this is my product state :

```
 const [product, setProduct] = useState({
    sku: "",
    description: "",
    unisex: true,
    woman: false,
    man: false,
    styles: [],
    materials: [],
    selectedFilesImages: [],
    selectedFilesVideos: [],
    name: "",
    discountPrice: "",
    categories: [],
    defaultPicture: [],
    shop: 0,
    variants: [],
    price: "",
  });
```

Here are my two functions that use useCallBack

```
 const addSelectedFilesImages = useCallback(
    (files) => {
      setProduct({ ...product, selectedFilesImages: files });
      console.log(product.selectedFilesImages);
    },
    [product.selectedFilesImages]
  );

  const addSelectedFilesVideos = useCallback(
    (files) => {
      setProduct({ ...product, selectedFilesVideos: files });
      console.log(product.selectedFilesVideos);
    },
    [product.selectedFilesVideos]
  );
```

here is my component to which i pass these functions

```
          <div className="col-sm-6">
              <FileManger
                addSelectedFiles={addSelectedFilesImages}
                selectFiles={product.selectedFilesImages}
                acceptFormat="image/*"
                videoOrPics="Drop files here or click to upload."
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <FileManger
                addSelectedFiles={addSelectedFilesVideos}
                selectFiles={product.selectedFilesVideos}
                acceptFormat="video/*"
                videoOrPics="Drop video files here or click to upload."
              />
            </div>
```

If i put product in the dependency everytime product is updated also FileManger is rendered , FileManager is based on product.selectedFilesVideos or product.selectedFilesImages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This linter warning gives you an option at the end – since you only need the `product` piece of state inside the `setProduct` function of the `useCallback` hook that you should use the functional syntax of `setProduct` which passes in the previous product as an argument.

It should look something like this:

```
const addSelectedFilesImages = useCallback((files) => {
  setProduct((prevProduct) => { // pass an inline function to setProduct
    return {...prevProduct, selectedFilesImages: files}
  })
}, [])
```

Comment: Resolved thanks. Can you link any documentation about this ? i would like to learn more about this :). thanks again

Comment: @HarpreetSingh [Functional Update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)  Here's the documentation about setting state with a function that receives the previous state. There isn't much documentation around the actual linter which adds a bit of confusion around linting react hooks & dependencies